# How to achieve "manual" failover with Apache Artemis?

Tags: activemq-artemis

I've configured a small cluster with just one primary/backup group.
So far, failover and failback work as expected.

But as this configuration is susceptible to network-isolation problems and I don't think, the pinger approach heals this sufficiently, I would prefer the backup to just be there and receive updates, but *not* automatically do a failover when the primary is unreachable.
Instead I want an intelligent human with better situational awareness to make the failover decision.

The decreased availability introduced by such a procedure is acceptable for us.

I've tried to get the backup to act this way (arbitrarily delaying failover) by using the following `ha-policy` > `replication` > `slave` parameters:

- `quorum-size`
- `quorum-vote-wait`
- `vote-retries`
- `vote-retry-wait`

but had no success so far.

Is it possible to somehow delay the automatic failover arbitrarily, and trigger the actual failover by changing the broker.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveMQ Artemis doesn't implement the functionality you're looking for - at least not in any automated way. I expect you could arbitrarily delay failover by setting `quorum-size` to something larger than the actual size of the cluster. However, there is no management operation to tell the backup broker to activate and become live. The only way you could do that would be to stop the broker, change the `ha-policy` to be a `master` and then restart the broker.